# How refresh child node value in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Swift and I have this structure:

```
groups {
 "fsfdsfsdf" {
    title: "Tasks"
    "todos" {
       "fsdfsdf": true
     }
}

let ref1 = Firebase(url: "https....io/groups/fsfdsfsdf/todos/fsdfsdf")
let ref2 = Firebase(url: "https....io/todos/fsdfsdf")
// after Edit I call this methods
ref1.updateChildValues(true) // true -> true observer doesn't catch
ref2.updateChildValues(editTodo)
```

Is there any method, that change true -> true and observer catch this change?

I can't use ref1.removeValue and then ref1.setValue(true)

Thanks for some advice.

Comment: Don't describe your code and data structure, but show them (as text, no screenshots). Create a minimal, complete reproduction of your problem. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please study the link I provided, as it explains what an MCVE is and why it is useful for both you and us. Then click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36679471/edit) link for your question to update it.